# How do you encrypt and decrypt files using your keychain?

Tags: 11.10, encryption

Remember this little guy over here?

[image]

He's no longer with us in Ubuntu 11.10. Now, a friend's sent me an encrypted file using a public key I *think* I have the key for in my keychain. How can I decrypt it?

Answer (score 4):

To view the keys known by gpg run: `gpg --list-keys`

Assuming the key pair is still in your system, open a terminal and do:

```
 gpg -d FILE.pgp
```

You may get a password prompt if the key requires it.

To encrypt a file, you can do:

```
gpg -e -r NAME FILE
```

The `-r` is for `--recipient` and is optional. It will prompt you for more input if needed.

Comment: So the option via nautilus is gone and will be gone? I had the same question and the terminal is not a good alternative for me.

Comment: This [can be scripted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) (note the paths will be different now) fairly easily if you wanted to restore something *like* the original.